# Pusher: Invalid signature: Expected HMAC SHA256 hex digest of

Tags: angular, asp.net-core, pusher, pusher-js

I got the following error message on subscribing to a private pusher channel:

> Invalid signature: Expected HMAC SHA256 hex digest of 124425.1545539:private-dash-98, but got e7ed825903c1e18931cceebba457270a6b1e79331387527ab97e430ba4d22068

**PUSHER CONSOLE**

```
Pusher : State changed : initialized -> connecting
Pusher : Connecting : {"transport":"xhr_streaming","url":"https://sockjs-
eu.pusher.com:443/pusher/app/XXXXXX?
protocol=7&client=js&version=4.2.2"}
Pusher : State changed : connecting -> connected ID 124425.1545539
Pusher : Event sent : {"event":"pusher:subscribe","data":
{"auth":"e24378fc4fcd43c36aa3:
e7ed825903c1e18931cceebba457270a6b1e79331387527ab97e430ba4d22068"
,"channel":"private-dash-98"}}
Pusher : Event recd : {"event":"pusher:error","data":
{"code":null,"message":"Invalid signature: Expected HMAC SHA256 hex digest 
of 124425.1545539:private-dash-98, but got 
e7ed825903c1e18931cceebba457270a6b1e79331387527ab97e430ba4d22068"}}
Pusher : Error : {"type":"WebSocketError","error":
{"type":"PusherError","data":{"code":null,"message":"Invalid signature: 
Expected HMAC SHA256 hex digest of 124425.1545539:private-dash-98, but got 
e7ed825903c1e18931cceebba457270a6b1e79331387527ab97e430ba4d22068"}}}
```

**CLIENT:** Angular 5 with [pusher-library](https://pusher.com/docs/javascript_quick_start) (Version 4.2.2)

```
Pusher.logToConsole = true;

        this.pusher = new Pusher(environment.pusherAppKey, {
            cluster: 'eu',
            encrypted: true,
            authEndpoint: environment.api + environment.pusherAuthUrl + '?areaId=' + this.locationService.selectedAreaId,
            auth: {
                headers: {
                    'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + this.authService.getAccessToken()
                }
            }
        });

        this.channel = this.pusher.subscribe('private-dash-98');
```

**BACKEND:** AspNet Core 2.0 Web Api with [pusher-library](https://github.com/pusher/pusher-http-dotnet)

```
    var authToken = pusher.Auth("private-dash-98", "124425.1545539");
    
    public string Auth(string channelName, string socketId)
    {
        var auth = _pusher.Authenticate(channelName, socketId);
        return auth.ToJson();
    }
```

Pusher auth-endpoint is returning the following:

```
{"auth":"e24378fc4fcd43c36aa3:e7ed825903c1e18931cceebba457270a6b1e79331387527ab97e430ba4d22068"}
```

The endpoint result seems totally correct. Is there any formatting issue?

Comment: Try printing out the `channelName` and `socketId` before you pass them to the `Auth` function and double check they are `private-dash-98` and `124425.1545539` respectively.

Comment: @WillSewell Now i pass the channel name and socketId directly (see backend edit: var authToken = pusher.Auth("private-dash-98", "124425.1545539"); --> Error still remains

Answer (score 0):

i solved my problem. I missed the **socket_id** in my api controller:

```
    [HttpPost("auth")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> GetAuthToken([FromQuery] int? areaId, [FromForm] string socket_id)
    {
        try
        {
            var pusher = new PusherManager(_appSettings);
            var authToken = pusher.Auth("private-area-" + areaId, socket_id);

            return Ok(authToken);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            _logger.LogError(ex.ToString());
            return new StatusCodeResult(500);
        }
    }
```

The above code now works as expected.